# NoClassDefFoundError when using Glassfish

Tags: java, exception, glassfish, noclassdeffounderror

I'm building a web application. When I run it on Tomcat, everything's working without a problem. But if I use Glassfish, I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError exception. Why is that? The class it's throwing an exception for is imported by Maven and as I said, Tomcat doesn't have any problem with running the application and finding the class. Why is there a problem with Glassfish?

A stacktrace I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openrdf/rio/RDFHandlerException    



at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)    

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)    

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)    

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)    

at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)    

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)    

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)    

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)    

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)    

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)    

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)    

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)    

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)    

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)    

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)    

at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)    

at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)    

at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)    

at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)    

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)    

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)    

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)    

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)    

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)    

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)    

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)    

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)    

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)    

at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)    

at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)    

at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)    

at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)    

at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)    

at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)    

at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)    

at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)    

at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)    

at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)    

at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)    

at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)    

at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)    

at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)    

at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)    

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)    

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openrdf.rio.RDFHandlerException    

at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)    

at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)    

... 45 more

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openrdf.rio.RDFHandlerException
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    at pl.psnc.synat.web.Service.runMapping(Service.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: mind pasting stack trace here?

Comment: Check for JAR's in lib of Tomcat & Glassfish may be your application have some dependency there...

Comment: Nishant - Stacktrace added.
Amandeep - I'm not sure what excatly you suggest to check

Comment: @krajol can you do print screen of your Jar's in Lib of Glassfish & Tomcat, and post it, make sure if you have installed Sesame i.e for RDF, In Glassfish.

Comment: From my understanding, incorrect initialization of the class path is the reason for NoClassFoundError occurrence , make sure that the class path is perfect and check for jars are at the exact location referred

Comment: @Amandeep Jiddewar I'm just starting my work with them so to be honest I'm not sure what you mean by Lib of Glassfish & Tomcat. If i understand it correctly and by lib of Glassfish you mean a folder 'lib' in a folder glassfish3122eclipsedefaultdomain of Glassfish that I have in my Eclipse workspace, then all subfolders of it are empty.

Comment: @THANGA Well, the problem is that I don't know how to actually make sure of it. I don't know how, what and where I should set up in Glassfish to make these class path correct.

Comment: @Amandeep: and I found all needed jars in a directory: glassfish3122eclipsedefaultdomain\eclipseApps\ProjectsName\WEB-INF\lib

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using openrdf. Please make sure that you have added [sesame](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsesamerioapi223jar.htm) and relevant jars in your runtime classpath. To make things more clear add an echo to your server startup script to display the CLASSPATH during the startup (for debugging)

Comment: I added dependencies to a Maven pom.xml. Shouldn't it be enough?
    <dependency>
    
   <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
    
   <artifactId>sesame-runtime</artifactId>
    
   <version>2.6.8</version>
    
   <scope>runtime</scope>
    
  </dependency>
    
  <dependency>
    
   <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
    
   <artifactId>sesame-rio-trix</artifactId>
    
   <version>2.6.8</version>
    
   <scope>runtime</scope>
    
  </dependency>

Comment: As I said, can you check if your deployement (in the server's tmp folder where the war gets unzipped) has these jars ?

Comment: I can find all needed jars only in a glassfish directory here:
\workspace\glassfish3122eclipsedefaultdomain\eclipseApps\ProjectsName\WEB-INF\lib

Comment: Fine. Can you start the server separately (from Terminal/Commandline) and deploy your WAR file and see if you are still getting this error ?

Comment: I'm using internal Glassfish as an Eclipse plug-in so to be honest, I'm not sure how I could do it with internal Glassfish

Comment: Go to http://glassfish.java.net/public/downloadsindex.html and download glassfish of your choice. Then post the findings. Please troubleshoot and write your findings before you ask any question. Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openrdf/rio/RDFHandlerException
```

It seems some jars files were missing after deploying war in the glassfish server.After deploying war please check your WEB-INF/LIB folder whether all jar files are included correctly?.

Comment: Yes, I can find all jars in a directory:
workspace\glassfish3122eclipsedefaultdomain\eclipseApps\MyProject\WEB-INF\lib

Comment: I think in your program did you used in this jar sesame/sesame-rio-api-2.2.3.jar.please verify after created war file present or not.

Comment: @krajol tat's fine.Have you added the jar's to classpath in eclipse?  make sure in the run configuration wizard-> classpath tab you should  find the jar which are required below this if not please add to it.

Comment: Yes, I added them to classpath but unfortunately it's not helping.

Comment: System.getproperty("java.classpath") It will print the classpath from there you can at least get an idea of your actual runtime classpath.